# Using a hash inside a let()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to DRY my code by putting a hash into a let and just calling the let but it doesn't seem to work. I get these errors:

```
syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' (SyntaxError) "email" => user.email,

syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...l" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
```

Here's my test:

```
describe '#create' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:user_params) { "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
  before(:each) { User.stub(:find_by_email).and_return(user) }
  it "should send find message to user model" do
    User.should_receive(:find_by_email)
    post :create, locale: "es", user: { user_params }
  end
  it "should set user to @user" do
    post :create, locale: "es", user: { "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
    assigns(:user).should eq(user)
  end
end
```

And here's my code:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'login'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're missing one pair of braces.

```
let(:user_params) { "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
```

should be

```
let(:user_params) { {"email" => user.email, "password" => user.password} }
```

Answer (score 9):

I would prefer a bit longer explanation.
When you write something like this:

```
let(:user_params) { "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
```

You call method `let` with one parameter (`:user_params`) and a block (in this case `{ "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }`). I will state it again:

```
let(:something) { some_method_call }
```

and

```
let(:something) do
  some_method_call
end
```

are equal. By using let, RSpec  sets variable to the **result of the block.** So, inside of the block, you need to return something. In this case - hash:

```
let(:user_params) do 
  { "email" => user.email, "password" => user.password }
end
```

That's it! You can find out more about let on [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Example/ExampleGroupMethods/let)